# Linear Algebra reflection question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T_1$ be a reflection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ about the plane $x = y$ and $T_2$ be a reflection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ about the plane 
$x = z$. Find standard matrix for the transformation $T_2 \cdot T_1$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? Did you try finding the standard matrix for the individual transformations?

Comment: I dont even know where to start. I just need a slight hint.

Answer (score 1):

To find the standard matrix $A_1$ for transformation $T_1$, we calculate
$$
T_1(e_1) = e_2\\
T_1(e_2) = e_1\\
T_1(e_3) = e_3
$$
So, it follows that
$$
A_1 = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}
$$
Follow a similar process for $A_2$.  Then, find the product $A_2 A_1$.